# Mediapipe image pose estimation ERROR: No subgraph in the model CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run

Tags: python, pose-estimation, mediapipe

I do like to **estimate the pose from an image** using `MediaPipe`, Following their [Tutorial](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/pose.html#python-solution-api) I'm getting this error:

- `ERROR: No subgraph in the model`
- `CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run`

while doing that!

> This error appears in **Ubuntu 20.04**, boost 1.71, mediapipe 0.8.10.1

The same code is working perfectly on Windows.

Can you please tell me how can I resolve this error? thanks in advance.

#### The code I'm using to draw the pose:

```py
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose

def draw_pose(image):
  """
  
  """
  BG_COLOR = (192, 192, 192)
  with mp_pose.Pose(
    static_image_mode=True,
    model_complexity=2,
    enable_segmentation=True,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5) as pose:
      image_height, image_width, _ = image.shape
      # Convert the BGR image to RGB before processing.
      results = pose.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

      if not results.pose_landmarks:
        return image

      annotated_image = image.copy()
      # Draw segmentation on the image.
      # To improve segmentation around boundaries, consider applying a joint
      # bilateral filter to "results.segmentation_mask" with "image".
      condition = np.stack((results.segmentation_mask,) * 3, axis=-1) > 0.1
      bg_image = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
      bg_image[:] = BG_COLOR
      annotated_image = np.where(condition, annotated_image, bg_image)
      # Draw pose landmarks on the image.
      mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
          annotated_image,
          results.pose_landmarks,
          mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
          landmark_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles.get_default_pose_landmarks_style())
  return annotated_image

path = "/media/user/WD/Vision_Module/"
imName = "frame.png"

img = cv2.imread(path+imName)
res = draw_pose(img)

cv2.imshow(res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

#### Error Log:

```
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
ERROR: No subgraph in the model.

WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
E20220111 09:38:55.000392  9542 calculator_graph.cc:805] INTERNAL: CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run: 
Calculator::Open() for node "poselandmarkbyroicpu__inferencecalculator__poselandmarkbyroicpu__InferenceCalculator" failed: ; interpreter_ilure (mediapipe/calculators/tensor/inference_calculator_cpu.cc:152) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/user/WD/Vision_Module/pose_est.py", line 24, in draw_pose
    results = pose.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mediapipe/python/solutions/pose.py", line 185, in process
    results = super().process(input_data={'image': image})
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mediapipe/python/solution_base.py", line 334, in process
    self._graph.wait_until_idle()
RuntimeError: CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run: 
Calculator::Open() for node "poselandmarkbyroicpu__inferencecalculator__poselandmarkbyroicpu__InferenceCalculator" failed: ; interpreter_ilure (mediapipe/calculators/tensor/inference_calculator_cpu.cc:152) 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/user/WD/Vision_Module/pose_est.py", line 49, in <module>
    res = draw_pose(img)
  File "/media/user/WD/Vision_Module/pose_est.py", line 38, in draw_pose
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mediapipe/python/solution_base.py", line 546, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mediapipe/python/solution_base.py", line 352, in close
    self._graph.close()
RuntimeError: CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run: 
Calculator::Open() for node "poselandmarkbyroicpu__inferencecalculator__poselandmarkbyroicpu__InferenceCalculator" failed: ; interpreter_ilure (mediapipe/calculators/tensor/inference_calculator_cpu.cc:152)
```

Answer (score 1):

model_complexity=0;
your code will run perfectly

Comment: sorry but your proposal is not the right solution! You can see that this code runs on google-colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10EXEiJjRdYueZ8_YseRD72ct3VIj3f_v?usp=sharing) without changing the complexity, the problem turns to be on the local machine version of `mediapipe`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: HI @Bilal, can you be more specific about the local machine version of mediapipe? What mediapipe version you used to achieve it and what version failed?

Comment: @jianinz thanks for your note, I have added these details to the question.